# How to force allocation of new page tables from userland on a Linux/ARM system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, page-tables

In order to reproduce a certain bug, it is necessary to be able to force creation of thousands of new page tables in the Linux kernel, and this must work on an ARM system. It must be done from an userland application without special privileges.

So more generally, when are new page tables created in the Linux kernel? I assume every time a new process is spawned. Does this mean that by fork()'ing 1000 times, we create 1000 new page tables in the kernel? Or is it not that simple?

Comment: The page tables will be shared between the processes.  They are 'copy on write' so you need to write a byte/word to every 4k so that a new page entry is forced to allocate.  A new allocation will be mapped to a COW zeroed page and only really allocated on an update.  Also, are you talking about an L1 page or L2 page?  There are only about 1000 L1 entries and no user space app can can map that much memory.

Comment: Er, your 1000 number seems suspicious.  With a 3G kernel 1 GB user space split, there are about 1000 L1 entries for user space.  A user space app could allocate that many page table entries, but they would definitely be pushing the memory system to start to OOM kill some processes.